# Open addon debugger during startup - Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

How to open addon debugger for specific addon during the browser startup like `--debug` switch of [`jpm`](https://github.com/mozilla/jpm) tool does?

---

**Edit:**
Addon debugger window can be obtained (using GUI) by clicking on 'Debug' button in Addons tab. It is basically a 'Browser Toolbox' window containing only sources relevant for selected addon.

I use nightly builds (currently v39).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what it's using to open an addon-scoped debugger, but it's probably an environment variable or a command line switch.

On linux you can inspect both via `ps we`.

For an unscoped debugger, refer to the help:

```
$ firefox -help

Usage: firefox [ options ... ] [URL]
       where options include:

[...]
  --jsdebugger       Open the Browser Toolbox.
[...]
```

Comment: I edited the answer regarding 'addon-scoped debugger'.  Using `ps` I found out that that debugger window runs in separate child process executed with parameter `-chrome chrome://browser/content/devtools/framework/toolbox-process-window.xul?addonID=id@id` and using separate special 'chrome_debugger_profile'. I search for some way to instruct parent firefox process to arrange all that for me.